# Piping function output to another function

Tags: zsh

I have the following two functions in my ~/.zshrc

```
func1 () {return 1}
func2 () {if [ "$1" = 1 ]; then echo "foo"; fi }
```

Calling `func2 1` prints `foo`. Calling `func1 | func2` prints nothing.

How can I pass the output of `func1` to `func2`?

Comment: `print 1`, not `return 1`. And then make `func2` read from standard input, or call it as `func2 $(func1)` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn. Context is me trying to learn zsh, not a problem I need to solve. I'm interested in understanding the difference between print and return, and why piping doesn't pass on a return statement

Comment: `return` is like `exit`. It doesn't produce any output.

Comment: And even if `func1` does write something, your current `func2` looks at a positional parameter and ignores anything piped to it.

Comment: OK, I see now that stdin is not viewed as a positional parameter. So I guess my question is: how do I do something (eg echo) with stdin?

Comment: You could use `cat`. This reads from stdin and writes to stdout.

Comment: `return` exits a function and sets the status code (`$?`). `print` writes its arguments to some file descriptor (see the option `-u`), and uses stdout if no file descriptor is provided. The two command don't have anything in common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return 1` does not actually print anything for `func2` to read, it merely sets the exit code for that function. You can use the `$?` or `$status` variable to check the exit code of the last command (they are identical):

```
func1; func2 $?
```

If you want to pipe any text output, you need to `print` it in `func1`, rather than return it:

```
func1 () { print 1 }
```

There are a number of ways to read from stdin, the shortest is to use `$(<&0)`:

```
if [[ $(<&0) = 1 ]]
```

`<&` reads from a file descriptor number, in this case `0` which is stdin.

You can also use `$(</dev/stdin)` to read from the special /dev/stdin file, but I'm not sure how portable that is. If you only care about running on Linux then that's a more readable way to do it, but I'm not sure how well it works on e.g. macOS, BSD, Windows, illumos or whatnot ([some background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36403/33645) on that, I haven't yet read through it).

There's also `read` (which has a bunch of options that you don't need here, but useful to know it exists):

```
read in
if [[ $in = 1 ]]
```

Or even just `cat`, which reads from stdin by default like most tools:

```
if [[ $(cat) = 1 ]]
```

In this case, that's a little bit silly, but if you want to filter or alter lines then using `grep` or `head` like this is more useful.

Putting it all together:

```
func1() {
    print '1'
}

func2() {
    if [[ $(<&0) = 1 ]]; then
        print 'One!'
    fi
}

func1 | func2
print 2 | func2
```

Will print `One!` once.

Comment: Amazing answer, clear and thorough. Thank you!